Encountering a Study Error When Trying to Draw Vertical Lines
I'm trying to draw vertical lines at the dates specified in my code, but I'm encountering a Study Error that says:

Error on bar 0: Objects positioned using xloc.bar_index cannot be drawn further than 500 bars into the future.

This is the code I ran:

//@version=5
indicator("ESPP MAY/NOV", overlay = true)

// Inputs for the user to select dates
var date1 = input.time(timestamp("2014-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 1")
var date2 = input.time(timestamp("2014-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 2")
var date3 = input.time(timestamp("2015-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 3")
var date4 = input.time(timestamp("2015-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 4")
var date5 = input.time(timestamp("2016-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 5")
var date6 = input.time(timestamp("2016-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 6")
var date7 = input.time(timestamp("2017-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 7")
var date8 = input.time(timestamp("2017-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 8")
var date9 = input.time(timestamp("2018-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 9")
var date10 = input.time(timestamp("2018-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 10")
var date11 = input.time(timestamp("2019-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 11")
var date12 = input.time(timestamp("2019-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 12")
var date13 = input.time(timestamp("2020-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 13")
var date14 = input.time(timestamp("2020-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 14")
var date15 = input.time(timestamp("2021-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 15")
var date16 = input.time(timestamp("2021-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 16")
var date17 = input.time(timestamp("2022-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 17")
var date18 = input.time(timestamp("2022-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 18")
var date19 = input.time(timestamp("2023-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 19")
var date20 = input.time(timestamp("2023-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 20")
var date21 = input.time(timestamp("2024-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 21")
var date22 = input.time(timestamp("2024-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 22")
var date23 = input.time(timestamp("2025-05-01 00:00"), "Select Date 23")
var date24 = input.time(timestamp("2025-11-01 00:00"), "Select Date 24")


// Function to draw vertical lines on the specified dates
draw_vertical_line(date) =>
    line.new(x1 = time, y1 = high, x2 = time, y2 = low, color = color.red, width = 6)

// Draw vertical lines on the selected dates
draw_vertical_line(date1)
draw_vertical_line(date2)
draw_vertical_line(date3)
draw_vertical_line(date4)
draw_vertical_line(date5)
draw_vertical_line(date6)
draw_vertical_line(date7)
draw_vertical_line(date8)
draw_vertical_line(date9)
draw_vertical_line(date10)
draw_vertical_line(date11)
draw_vertical_line(date12)
draw_vertical_line(date13)
draw_vertical_line(date14)
draw_vertical_line(date15)
draw_vertical_line(date16)
draw_vertical_line(date17)
draw_vertical_line(date18)
draw_vertical_line(date19)
draw_vertical_line(date20)
draw_vertical_line(date21)
draw_vertical_line(date22)
draw_vertical_line(date23)
draw_vertical_line(date24)


I'm not sure what "bars" indicate or what the units consist of. I tried adjusting it so I'm only using dates within a few days apart from the current date, but it still gives me the same error. I also tried only using dates that have available data, meaning past dates, and that doesn't work either. Can someone help debug this code, or at least point to me documentation that explains what the error means?

Since I doubt you got any interest to understand what chatGPT did wrong or even will flag the right answer or leave a "thank you" but only came to extract some free working "hours" from others, I safe myself from explaining the details.
Here is a working example:
//@version=5
indicator("vLine", overlay = true)

i_date = input.time(timestamp("2024-01-01 00:00"), "Select Date 1")


draw_vertical_line(date) =>
    line.new(x1 = date, y1 = open, x2 = date, y2 = open, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 50), width = 1, extend = extend.both)

draw_vertical_line(i_date)


Thank you for the help, didn't know I had to use xloc.bar_time instead of xloc.bar_index
